# On IntelliJ IDEA. Unable to add String to ArrayList<String>. Error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'add' "

Tags: java, intellij-idea, symbols

```
static List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>(asList("Hello", "Goodbye"));
commands.add("Hi!");
```

Compiler errors:

Error:(37, 17) java: `<identifier>` expected

Error:(37, 18) java: illegal start of type

Those locations are after and before the open parenthesis on .add();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class MyClass {

static List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>(asList("Hello", "Goodbye"));
commands.add("Hi!");

}
```

is illegal. You cannot call a method inside class definition.

To make it work use a static block:

```
 class MyClass {

    static List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>(asList("Hello", "Goodbye"));
      static {
         commands.add("Hi!");
      }
    }
```